# Problem accessing values from jibjectArray in JNI

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to access values from jObjectArray in JNI and trying to get integer value from it. I am passing Object ...arguments from Java side to pass variable args to JNI. I want to get int, double, string values from jObjectArray in it. I am trying to extract int value from first object element.

calling send from MainActivity.java

```
        int val = 3;
        long ts = 0;

        sendData(val, ts);

public boolean send(Object ... arguments) {
        Log.d(TAG, "sendData called");
        return nativeSend(arguments);
    }
```

in native send: getting arguments as jobjectArray

```
int objectsCount = env->GetArrayLength(arguments); //Works fine to get Array length

    jobject obj = env->GetObjectArrayElement(arguments, 0);

    jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
    if(cls == NULL){
        LOGD("cannot find FindClass(java/lang/Integer)");
    }
    jmethodID getVal = env->GetMethodID(cls, "intValue", "()I");
    if(getVal == NULL){
        LOGD("Couldnot find Int getValue()");
    }

    int i = env->CallIntMethod(obj, getVal); //getting error obj underlined:
```

Error: JVM object referenced by 'obj' is of type 'Object' and it does not have access to method 'intValue()' declared in class 'Integer'.

Also tried:

```
int val = reinterpret_cast<int>(obj);
```

But this gives some garbage value.

How can I get the integer value which I had passed in jObjectArray. Can someone explain, I am a newbie in this concept?

Comment: Do you get this error from android studio itself? It cannot know that the first element of your array is actually an Integer. Your approach seems fine, so can't you disable the error and compile anyway?

Comment: There does not seem to be a way to suppress this inspection in Android Studio and I would not advise disabling it, but you can still build and run. (just tested)

Comment: No, I am not able to run it. I am getting error.

Comment: A compilation error? An error in logcat? The "JVM object referenced by ..." does not stop you from building.

Comment: Take a look here for a sample of accessing elements inside array of Objects: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/blob/master/recipes/recipeNo069/c/recipeNo069_PassList.c